# c shell get the ith+1 element of an array. eg array[i+1]

Tags: csh

How do i get the value from  `echo $argv[$i + 1]`?

I have tried

```
$argv[\` expr $i + 1 \`]
```

but i get a Missing -. error

```
while ( $i <= $# )
    echo $argv[$i]
    echo $argv[$i + 1]
    set i = \` expr $i + 2 \
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use arithmetic expressions inside brackets in csh, but you can use another variable:

```
while( $i < $# )
    echo $argv[$i]
    @ j = i + 1
    echo $argv[$j]
    @ i++
end
```